# Failures running rspec tests for the WebSphere Liberty Profile Buildpack

Tags: websphere-liberty

I am using the open source repo for the OSS Cloud Foundry Liberty Profile Buildpack and running into the following failures when executing `bundle exec rspec`

*681 examples, 3 failures*
Failed examples:

```
rspec ./spec/bin/compile_spec.rb:49 # compile script should work with the liberty WEB-INF case
rspec ./spec/bin/compile_spec.rb:65 # compile script should also work with the zipped up server case
rspec ./spec/bin/compile_spec.rb:82 # compile script pass environment variable directory
```

The 3 failures have a common stack ...

> ```
> 1) compile script should work with the liberty WEB-INF case
> Failure/Error: expect(result).to be_success
>  expected `#<Process::Status: pid 84398 exit 1>.success?` to return true, got false
> ```

```
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-expectations-3.0.4/lib/rspec/expectations/fail_with.rb:30:in `fail_with'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-expectations-3.0.4/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:37:in `handle_failure'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-expectations-3.0.4/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:48:in `handle_matcher'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-expectations-3.0.4/lib/rspec/expectations/expectation_target.rb:54:in `to'
 # ./spec/bin/compile_spec.rb:59:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /Users/kelapr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open3.rb:208:in `popen_run'
 # /Users/kelapr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open3.rb:90:in `popen3'
 # ./spec/bin/compile_spec.rb:53:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/bin/compile_spec.rb:124:in `with_memory_limit'
 # ./spec/bin/compile_spec.rb:52:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /Users/kelapr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb:83:in `mktmpdir'
 # ./spec/bin/compile_spec.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:148:in `instance_exec'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:148:in `block in run'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:301:in `with_around_example_hooks'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:145:in `run'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:494:in `block in run_examples'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:490:in `map'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:490:in `run_examples'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:457:in `run'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `map'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `block in run_specs'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:54:in `report'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:108:in `run_specs'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
 # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

Cans someone guide us on how to resolve these failures that seem to stem from an `Open3.popen3` call from within a `Dir.mktmpdir` block. These results from the master branch of https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ibm-websphere-liberty-buildpack/

-Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see such failures in the [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/cloudfoundry/ibm-websphere-liberty-buildpack) system. Also, testing on a local machine didn't result in any failures. Do you see any other errors in the test output? In case of a failure, there should be messages starting with `stdout:` and `stderr:` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

The issues with the long running tests with these failure is that stack traces are very poor at figuring out what actually happened. We determined the root cause of these failures as **lack of network connectivty**.